# How to add glowing effect to a line for OpenGL?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, bloom

How can I add a glowing effect to a line that I draw? I'm using OpenGL for Linux.

Comment: This is commonly called "adding [bloom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect))", to aid in your search. There is a nice section in how to do it [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/chadvanced.html#fig-BloomTriptych)

Comment: There is also a great summary of glow effects [here](http://prideout.net/archive/bloom/)

Answer (score 10):

You can implement the **radial blur** effect described on [Nehe Lesson 36](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/radial_blur__rendering_to_a_texture/18004/). The main idea is to render the drawing to a texture, and do that N times with a small offset after each render, until the drawing is ready to be copied to the framebuffer.

I've written a small demo that uses [Qt and OpenGL](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/qtLogoBlurGL). You can see **the original drawing** (without the blur) below:

[image]

The next image shows the **drawing with the blur** effect turned on:

[image]

I know it's not much, but it's a start.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the answer, but I think the correct path has been changed to https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/qtLogoBlurGL

Answer (score 8):

I too once hoped there was a very simple solution to this, but unfortunately it is a little complicated, at least for a beginner.

The way glowing effects are implemented today, regardless of API (D3D,OpenGL) is with pixel/fragment-shaders. It usually involves multiple render passes where you render your scene, then render a pass where only "glowing objects" are visible, then you apply a bloom  pixelshader and compose them together.

See the link provided by @Valmond for details

Edit:

It should be added that this can be achieved with deferred rendering, where normals, positions and other information like a "glow flag" is rendered to a texture, i.e. stored in different components of the texture. Then a shader will read from the textures and do lightning computations and post-processing effects in a single pass since all data it needs is available from that rendered texture.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out : http://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch21.html

It explains easily how to make glow effects.

Comment: That really doesn't explain much about how to do it. It just talks about the process and not the actual implementation

Answer (score 1):

Without using shaders, you might also try rendering to texture and doing a radial blur.
As a starting point check out [NeHe-Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/radial_blur__rendering_to_a_texture/18004/).