# Make graphics to glow/halo

Tags: c++, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add glowing effect to a line for OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293839/how-to-add-glowing-effect-to-a-line-for-opengl)

I would like to get help for making my graphics glow. I would like to do it the same way as in Tron 2.0 game, without using advanced stuff like shaders etc. Mainly because my video card isn't capable. 
I know I can get the technique from site: [wanted outcome](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2107/realtime_glow.php)
But I don't know, how to do it in OpenGL in c++. Maybe somebody has code for doing it or step by step guide or can point me in direction where to obtain code or step by step guide for doing it. Let's say that my program draws a maze like in the picture below:

[image]

And now I would like to get that maze lines something like the picture below:

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14082741/176769) provides a brief description of a technique, and shares **code** & **images** of the achieved effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have done exactly the same maze type of game, with glowing lines :)

The way we did it was to add rectangles around lines, with glow textures.

Sorry for not adding step-to-step tutorial, but at least you have the general idea there.

Comment: I would love to see a step-by-step of your approach. Maybe you can share it in a blog or something, and then improve your answer with the link to it.